# ViewController linked to storyboard of a different project?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I have a ViewController class that is a subclass of UIViewController in an old xcode project.  I want to use that same ViewController class in a new project so I am copying the .h and .m files to folder of that project.  However, when I look at the .h file, the IBOutlets are automatically linked to the storyboard of the old project.  I don't see anything in the .h or .m files that is pointing to the storyboard file of the old project. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try to run a clean on the new project?

Answer (score 0):

The connections (the little circles on the left side of the editor) are made by the storyboard or xib files and not by the .h or .m files.

The easiest solution to break that connection would be to change the class name (NewViewController or something of that nature). If that creates too many problems you could change the names of all the connections which would also sever the connection.

Basically, just find a way of making the circles on the left side of the editor empty rather than full.